# Freemarker - Evaluating an expression one after another

Tags: freemarker

the issue here is that i have both **index** and **c** as the evaluated expressions, after **index[1]** is evaluated, it will serve as a parameter to the **userDetails**. Hence, an e.g. like **c.firstname**.

```
   <#ftl encoding='UTF-8'>
   <#list param?chunk(3) as index>
       <#list userDetails as c>
           ${c.index[1]}
       </#list>
   </#list>
```

However, i am assuming that Freemarker is evaluating all the expressions at one time, hence when this piece of code is being run, **index[1]** is not evaluated yet. Thus, i'm getting this error instead.

```
FreeMarker template error:
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> c.index  [in template "src/template_fixedlength.ftl" at line 5, column 19]
```

Does anyone of you know of any workaround for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The evaluation happens left to right in this case, like if it was `(c.index)[1]`. This is like so in pretty much all other languages too. If I understand well, `index[1]` would evaluate to the string `"firstname"`, and you want `c.firstname` in effect. Then, the syntax is `c[index[1]]`.